# Car-like robot navigation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am building a MIT-Racecar, a so called "Car-like robot". I found a lot of features in current ROS navigation stack did not work on Car-like-robot. I am wondering if there is any existing navigation ROS software for car-like-robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298976/car-like-robot-navigation/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-29**:
What features?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-30**:
I'm guessing planning, as the default local planners do not work with Ackermann steering. You'll probably want to take a look at [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner).

I do +1 @jayess' question though: @AutoCar: simply stating that things "did not work" is not enough.

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-30**:
mostly in planning, since car-like-robot can't rotate in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can try teb_local_planner.
Yes, car-like-robot can't rotate in place, so you can set the parameter min_turning_radius of this planner as you need, and there's a detailed tutorial for Planning for car-like robots. [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots)

Hope it will help.

---

Originally posted by [ZengLei](https://answers.ros.org/users/33271/zenglei/) with karma: 36 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1